# Accessing a multi-level association fails (ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I cannot figure out how to access a multiple-level association in my views.

I have 3 main models: Categories, Activities and Votes (leaving out irrelevant lines):

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  # Many-to-many relationship with model Activity
  has_and_belongs_to_many :activity, dependent: :destroy
  # Link to votes
  has_many :vote, through: :activity
end
```

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  # Many-to-many relationship with model Activity
  has_and_belongs_to_many :category
  # An Activity can have multiple votes
  has_many :vote, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  # Many (users and activities) to one (votes) relationship
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :activity
end
```

I have a joining table between Categories and Activities for the Many-to-Many relationship.

What I would like to accomplish is, in a Category view, display the number of Activities in that Category as well as the number of Votes in that Category *(through Votes on Activities)*. The first works just fine:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= category.activity.ids.count %>
<% end %>
```

The latter, displaying the number of votes, doesn't (`undefined method "vote"`) - which is in the same block as above:

```
<%= category.activity.vote.ids.count  %>
```

Neither of the 2 below lines my Category controller work for this purpose:

```
  def index
    # With this I can already access the associated Activities, but not the Votes
    @categories = Category.all()
  end
```

```
  def index
    # Changing the Category controller as follows seems to have no effect on being able to access the number of votes
    @categories = Category.joins({:activity => :vote}).group('category_id').order('COUNT(activities.id) DESC')
  end
```

I must be missing something here?

// Edit: this is what I've got now in my view based on Neel's suggestion:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <% category.activity.each do |activity| %>
    <%= activity.vote.ids.count %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `activity` should be plurlized, since it's a many. Using the right naming will help you understand why this doesn't work, `category.activities.vote` doesn't make much sense, you can't access `.vote` on a collection of activities.

Comment: Thanks I now see that and immediately changed the naming to prevent this for myself in the future. Where would I put the logic for adding up all the votes of all the activities per category?

Comment: There are a lot of problems with the code in this question. `has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy` not `vote`. `has_and_belongs_to_many :categories` etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I had a look through all my MVCs and corrected them to the right naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

can I see your logs?

I think you have multiple activities here

**'<%= category.activity.vote.ids.count  %>'**

try to find votes from the below code.

**'<%= category.activity.first.vote.ids.count  %>'**

Comment: Thanks! I now indeed see that I was getting back an array of Activities, which makes sense now that you pointed me to it. Your suggested code works, but instead of a list of no. of `Votes` for each `Activity` per `Category` I would like to display the total number for `Votes` per `Category`. But I'm not sure how and where to put this logic. Maybe it shouldn't be done in the view?

Comment: you can move that logic to helper